# Could not mock return value of service

Tags: grails, spock

i have a problem with an controller test. I try to mock a return value of a service method, but it do not return a specific object and call the service method anyway.
The Test-Method:

```
def "shouldReturnStatus"() {
    given:
    controller.repairService.getRepair('123465') >> repair;
    when:
    controller.status();
    then:
    response.text == '{"currentStatus":"Repair was found.","repairFound":true}'
}
```

The repair mock is declared in the setup method.

The Controller-Method:

```
def status() {      
    String repairCode = params.repairCode;
    if(repairCode == null || repairCode.isEmpty()) {
        log.info("REPARATURSTATUSABFRAGE: Reparaturcode wurde nicht angegeben")
        renderEmptyRepairCode();
    } else if(repairService.getRepair(repairCode)) {
        Repair repair = repairService.getRepair(repairCode);
        if(repair) {
            log.info("REPARATURSTATUSABFRAGE: Reparaturstatus mit Code " + repairCode + " erfolgreich ausgegeben.")
            Customer customer = repair.getCustomer();
            renderRepairStatus(repair, customer);
        }
    } else {
        log.info("REPARATURSTATUSABFRAGE: Reparatur mit Code " + repairCode + " nicht gefunden.")
        renderRepairNotFound(repairCode);
    }       
}
```

The repairService-Method:

```
def getRepair(String repairCode) {      
    Repair repair = Repair.findByRepairCode(repairCode);
    if(repair == null) {
        String upperCaseRepairCode = repairCode.toUpperCase();
        repair = Repair.findByRepairCode(upperCaseRepairCode);
    }       
    return repair;      
}
```

I've mocked the repairService in the setup-Method

```
repairService = Mock(RepairService);
```

I think the code of the service method don't really matters, because I mocked the return value of this method. Or did i understand something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your test:

```
def "shouldReturnStatus"() {
    given:
    controller.repairService = Mock(RepairService)
    controller.repairService.getRepair('123465') >> repair

    when:
    controller.status();
    then:
    response.text == '{"currentStatus":"Repair was found.","repairFound":true}'
}
```

If I interpret your question right, you have created an instance variable inside your Spec, of type Mock(RepairService). That does not mean that your controller will use this mocked service. You need to actually assign it to the controller.